Issues with WineHQ signing key, PostgreSQL on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I am using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and I am facing the following issues:

WineHQ Signing Key: The signing key is old and needs to be updated to a new key.
Installing PostgreSQL: I encountered an error message while installing PostgreSQL that says there are two signing keys and one of them needs to be removed.

I am a beginner, so please keep it very simple. I am in a sanctioned country and have attempted multiple times to install WineHQ, Gnome-tweaks, and PostgreSQL. Due to the need for DNS changes and VPN, the installations have been incomplete or the programs have been removed.
If anyone can help me, I would be very grateful.

1 question per post is the rule on this site. I see 3 totally separate questions. Please edit and correct as needed.
